# cannot open the debug->windows->threads tool

Tags: visual-studio

I've been using VS Community 2017 for about 6 months now. During this time I have always been able to see the threads window. I just closed the window and cannot get it back. I may have done something else at the same time, but I don't know what. 
The project is in Debug mode, I am launching it Local Windows Debugger.
When at a breakpoint or paused, from the menu I select debug -> windows -> threads, but nothing happens. At the top of the IDE I see a pull down box named Thread: with all of my threads, but I cannot see the Threads window.

Other items such as modules or call stack can be opened. I also tried restarting VS and updating to 15.3.5

Comment: Use Window > Reset Window Layout when you've mangled the window layout beyond hope.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the threads window was hidden somehow. I went to tools -> import and export setting and reset to factory default. threads window is now visible.

I see there is an auto hide control. must have hit that instead of delete.